# Timezone issue with .createEvent()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have issues with the event time zone in my script. I browsed through many topics like this, but my beginner's skills did not allow me to transcribe the solutions to my own case ...

Here's my script:

```
function book1() {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var responses = form.getResponses();
var len = responses.length;
var last = len - 1;
var items = responses[last].getItemResponses();
var email = responses[last].getRespondentEmail();
var equipment = items[1].getResponse();
var datestart = items[2].getResponse();
var dateend = items[3].getResponse();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(equipment)[0];
Logger.log(datestart);
Logger.log(dateend);
var start = new Date(datestart);
var end = new Date(dateend);
Logger.log('start '+start);
Logger.log('end '+end);

var allEvents = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(equipment)[0].getEvents(start, end);

if (allEvents.length < 1) {
var event = cal.createEvent(equipment, start, end)
.addGuest(email);

MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Equipment " +equipment+ " booking confirmed",
    htmlBody: "Equipment " +equipment+ " available, please return it by " +dateend+ " and scan the QR code when returning it.",
  });
}

else {
  var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("calendariframe").getBlob();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Equipment  " +equipment+ " not available",
    htmlBody: blob.getDataAsString(),
  });};
```

}

I can't find the right way to use `getTimezoneOffset()` or `Utilities.formatDate` in the right way. Would you have any advice on where to integrate them in my script so that the createEvent() works in GMT+1?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your issue? events are normally inserted at the timezone of the calendar itself.

Comment: For me, the timezone is GMT-4, and the start var returns: start Sat Mar 19 2022 14:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), while the calendar is set on GMT+1.

Comment: Have you set up the script and the spreadsheet time zones. They can be adjusted individually.

Comment: I don't use spreadsheet, only a form and the scripts. Is there a way to adjust the script timezone individually?

Comment: Found it, I will try now! Thanks!

Comment: I can't actually see where to adjust the time zone in a spreadsheet any longer.  It seems to be tied to local time zone which makes sense...wonder why it wasn't always like that.

Comment: The solution of changing the scripts project timezone worked. I had to go to the settings and display appscript.json.

Comment: Hi, would you consider posting an answer explaining the solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found thanks to Cooper!

I went to the scripts project settings, checked the "Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor" box, went to the appsscript.json script and changed the timezone ID.

Comment: You can also go back to the legacy editor and do it in project properties